# Sagemaker processing job with PySpark and Step Functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

this is my problem:
I have to run a Sagemaker processing job using custom code written in PySpark. I've used the Sagemaker SDK by running these commands:

```
spark_processor = sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor(
        base_job_name="spark-preprocessor",
        framework_version="2.4",
        role=role_arn,
        instance_count=2,
        instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
        max_runtime_in_seconds=1800,
    )

    spark_processor.run(
        submit_app="processing.py",
        arguments=['s3_input_bucket', bucket_name,
                   's3_input_file_path', file_path
                   ]
    )
```

Now I have to automate the workflow by using Step Functions. For this purpose, I've written a lambda function to do that but I receive the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sagemaker'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

This is my lambda function:

```
import sagemaker

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    spark_processor = sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor(
        base_job_name="spark-preprocessor",
        framework_version="2.4",
        role=role_arn,
        instance_count=2,
        instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
        max_runtime_in_seconds=1800,
    )

    spark_processor.run(
        submit_app="processing.py",
        arguments=['s3_input_bucket', event["bucket_name"],
                   's3_input_file_path', event["file_path"]
                   ]
    )
```

My question is: How can I create a step in my state machine for running a PySpark code using Sagemaker processing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

sagemaker sdk is not installed by default in the lambda container environment: you should include it in the lambda zip that you upload to s3.

There are various ways to do this, one of the easiest is to deploy your lambda with [Serverless Application Model (SAM) cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html). In this case it might be enough to place `sagemaker` in the `requirements.txt` placed in the folder that contains your lambda code, and SAM will ensure that the dependency is included in the zip.

Alternatively you can create the zip manually with `pip install sagemaker -t lambda_folder` but you should execute this command in an Amazon Linux OS, for example with an EC2 with the appropriate image or in a Docker container. Search for "python dependencies in aws lambda" for more info.